Draw a TikZ picture with forces and a rope
I am trying to draw a TikZ picture of this screenshot.

I was trying to adapt this template which I found when asking Google and which looks a lot like the picture I am aiming at. But I did not succeed.
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head

\colorlet{myred}{red!65!black}
\tikzstyle{ground}=[preaction={fill,top color=black!10,bottom color=black!5,shading angle=20},
                    pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.3,minimum height=0.6]
\tikzstyle{mass}=[line width=0.6,red!30!black,fill=red!40!black!10,rounded corners=1,
                  top color=red!40!black!20,bottom color=red!40!black!10,shading angle=20]
\tikzstyle{rope}=[brown!70!black,line width=2] %very thick
\def\rope#1{ \draw[black,line width=2.3] #1; \draw[rope] #1; }

% FORCES SWITCH
\tikzstyle{force}=[->,myred,thick,line cap=round]
\newcommand{\vbF}{\vb{F}}
\newcommand{\vbT}{\vb{T}}
\newboolean{showforces}
\setboolean{showforces}{true}

\begin{document}
% VERTICAL ceiling
\def\h{0.6} % mass height
\def\w{0.7} % mass width
% VERTICAL ceiling 2
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\W{2.0} % ground width
  \def\D{0.2} % ground depth
  \def\H{1.5} % ground depth
  \def\y{0} % mass y coordinate
  \coordinate (M) at (0,0);
  \rope{(-0.4*\W,1.05*\H) -- (M) -- (0.4*\W,1.05*\H)}
  \draw[ground] (-\W/2,\H) rectangle++ (\W,\D);
  \draw (-\W/2,\H) --++ (\W,0);
  \draw[mass] (M)++(-\w/2,0) rectangle++ (\w,-\h) node[midway] {$m$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Do you see an easy way to adapt the template or to draw this picture otherwise?

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

What troubles you?

Just a note: \defing single letters is unwise because it could overwrite something important. You might use \pgfmathsetmacro instead, or a \newcommand.

Your MWE is not close what you after ... So I need to draw desired sketch from scratch:
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=3mm]},semithick},
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.1pt},
  S/.style = {pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt}]},
              pattern color=gray},
every edge quotes/.append style = {pos=0.3, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\draw[double=gray!30, double distance=2mm]
    (0.5,0) -- ++ (0,4) node (a) [dot,label=$A$] {} 
    (4.5,0) -- ++ (0,4) node (b) [dot,label=$B$] {};
\node (p) [dot, label=$P$] at (2.5,3) {};
%
\draw   (a) -- (p) 
            -- (b)
        (p) -- ++ (0,-0.5) node (g) [minimum size=8mm, fill=gray!50, below] {$m$};
\draw[arr, shorten >=11mm]  (p) edge ["$\vec{F}_l$" '] (a)
                            (p) edge ["$\vec{F}_r$"  ] (b);
\draw[arr]            (g.south)  to  ["$\vec{G}$"] ++ (0,-1);
%
\path[S]        (0,0) rectangle (5,-0.25);
\draw[thick]    (0,0) -- ++ (5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Great Zarko. This is better than the 1st picture.

Wow, that's fantastic, thanks a lot!!
